# Git Desktop - Received HTTP code 407 from proxy after CONNECT

Tags: git, github-desktop

I'm using git desktop and while fetching or pushing my changes I'm getting below error. I'm not using any cmd. What are other ways to get this resolved.

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/ABCD.git/': Received HTTP code 407 from proxy after CONNECT
```

Comment: You're behind a proxy server that's misbehaving when trying to talk to an HTTPS endpoint. Is this a corporate network, or have you just misconfigured your system proxies?

Comment: Yes, it's a corporate network.